# Is Jehovah's Witness considered halachically different than other Christians?

Tags: halacha, christianity

Jehovah's Witnesses believe in one God with J. being a prophet/son of god, kind of like Muhammad or Elijah the prophet. They don't believe he IS god, and they don't believe in the Trinity. It probably falls under the category of *Shituf*, perhaps not even that.

If that is indeed the case then is there any halachik differences? (Like entering/working in such a  church.)

Comment: I can't speak for this site, but this is definitely on topic at https://christianity.stackexchange.com and there are active and knowledgeable JWs there.

Comment: Same (being nice here)"shtuff", different denomination. Same "scriptures". I don't know of Muhammad or Elijah ever being referred to as "son of god".  Kind of like shoveling out an outhouse and saying the shtuff with corn might be ok.